# How to add etire lines of a shell command output to Makefile define?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wrote in `Makefile`

```
define deploy_meta
$(shell git log -n 2 --oneline | awk '{print "commit"NR ": " $0}')
commit: nogit-$(timestamp)
tag: nogit-$(timestamp)
deployed-from: $(shell hostname)
deployed-by: $(USER)
deploy-date: $(shell date -u '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
endef
```

but if gives me

```
$cat .deploy    
commit1:  commit2: 
commit: nogit-1669806282
tag: nogit-1669806282
...
```

Command itself

```
git log -n 2 --oneline | awk '{print "commit"NR ": " $0}'
```

works fine and gives two lines. It is evident, that make feels it, since it prints two "commit#" words. But it doesn't print content. Why?

Comment: `$0` in your command will be interpreted by `make`.  Escape the `$` by doubling it: ... `$$0` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is simple enough: Make expands `$0` here (to nothing).  You need `$$0`.

If you want two lines, though, [`$(shell)` is *also* part of your problem here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html):

> The `shell` function provides for make the same facility that backquotes (`` '`' ``) provide in most shells: it does *command expansion*. This means that it takes as an argument a shell command and expands to the output of the command. The only processing `make` does on the result is to **convert each newline (or carriage-return / newline pair) to a single space**. If there is a trailing (carriage-return and) newline it will simply be removed.

(emphasis mine).  You'll need a completely different approach, e.g., use `$(shell)` to produce a file, then `include` that file, for instance.